# Magento 2.3 product Customer Group pricing not working in shopping cart

Tags: magento2.3

Magento 2.3 product's customer group pricing while adding the product to the cart. It shows the regular price of the product in the cart. The same issue is the special price.

Any help would be appreciated..!

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Have you ran indexer:reindex command?

Comment: yes, ran indexer:reindex command.